# Weird styling issues with nav bar and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got two styling issues. You'll find the [full fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1292/). Please note I'm not using any media queries.

1st issue:

Upon re-sizing the browser unlike the header when scrolling horizontally (left or right) my footer seems to wrap itself round its content and leave a massive gap to the right

For example please re-size the browser to a width of 624px and then try scrolling to the right .. you will see this gap to the right of the footer.

I've set the footer width to a 100% but yet its wrapping itself round. Could it be the

```
overflow: hidden;
```

property?

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

My desired outcome should be the footer appearing from one end of the browser to the other.

2nd issue:

Again this is to do with my browser resizing. Upon re-sizing the browser my navigation bar which is floated roght in the header seems to jump/move to the next line. I attempted several things as seen here but no luck.

Comment: At first sight i can say that the second issue is due to the content of your header - currently there seems to be no logo displayed, but it takes up spaces. on gowing below ~ 700 px your logo is in the first line and nav bar is in the second - just increase the min-width of header to solve it

Comment: @ Frank P .. ur right regarding the logo but i need the logo to be that wide ... i've changed the min-width of the header .. i increased but same result .. i also attempted adding the header into the main_div but still no luck .. see screenshot of what is happening here .. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lBPXKQBuQHUnVEVk1aSElLMU0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`width: 100%` will size an element to the dimensions of its parent, unfortunately sizing a child to a particular dimension larger than a container won't automatically size the container to the same dimensions.

Basically the set-up you have is this:

```
body
  .maindiv (width: 1280px)
  footer   (width: 100%)
```

The footer is sized to the dimensions of the body, which, by default will be the width of the viewport. So this is why your footer is getting limited and not sizing to the size of `.maindiv`. There are three quick solutions to this.

1. Size your footer to the same width as `.maindiv` i.e. `width: 1280px`
2. Apply `float: left` to the body. This is a trick that forces the container element (i.e. the body) to wrap to its child elements dimensions. This should cause the body to take the same width as `.maindiv` automatically. There may be some unexpected side-effects of doing this however as floats can cause layout oddities.
3. Or you could move your footer inside `.maindiv`, that way it will automatically size itself to the right dimensions.

With regard to your other issue Frank Provost has commented correctly about that, so following his advice should fix that issue.

#### Update

As Frank mentioned, increasing your `header` `min-width` until the problem goes away is the solution, you can do this by trial and error, or you can measure it. In order to get your header to stop misbehaving you'll need a `min-width` of around `min-width: 770px;`. Basically setting the minimum width will prevent the internal children from wrapping down to the next row, but this will only work if the minimum width is the same or larger than the total horizontal width that the children occupy.

> Note: If you add extra items to your header you will have to recalculate this value. A quick and visual way to do this on a Mac OSX operating system (the one I'm using now) is to use the region snapshot feature. Using **CMD** + **SHIFT** + **4** you'll get a target cursor that will allow you to draw a measured region on the screen. This allows you to measure pixels, you don't actually have to take the screen shot by hitting **ESC**. I'm sure there are equivalents to this for other operating systems. If not you can just measure each individual child using the browser's inspector, and then sum the result.

Comment: THANKS Pebbl ... Suggestion 3 seems the best for me .. I've implemented it .. see it here .. https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1293/ ... Now i need to solve my 1st issue .. any ideas

Comment: Tried Frank P suggestion but as expalined above still facing same issue ... i.e. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lBPXKQBuQHUnVEVk1aSElLMU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ANM ~ I've updated my answer with further details which should sort you out. Also, just so you are aware, in order to send a comment to someone you have to use their exact username. So it isn't certain that Frank Provost would have seen your comment above, as his username is FrankProvost. Just typing @F at the beginning of your comment should bring up an autocomplete of the available usernames to choose from.

Comment: just wanted to mention when trying to find `min-width` or really any other trial and error CSS it's absolutely indispensable to familiarize yourself with the your browser's web inspector where you can live update styles in real time and watch things bounce around on the screen.  Not sure about how flexible every browser is but with Firefox you can easily create a min-width rule, click on the value and hold down up arrow until you find the value you want.

Comment: @billynoah: thanks for the follow up on Frank Provost's suggestion ... i used firefox inspector to change the min-width to 770px and all went well .. as the nav bar is prevented from wrapping down to the next row ..

Comment: @Pebbl: just used autocomplete to write this message .. thanks for this tip